# Error in Typescript Overloaded Function Signatures

Tags: typescript

When I use call signatures for overloading function types:

```
type Sum = {
    (a: string, b: string): string
    (a: number, b: number): number
}

let sum: Sum = function(
    a: number|string,
    b: number|string
): number|string {
    if (typeof a == "number" && typeof b == "number") {
        return a + b;
    }
    if (typeof a == "string" && typeof b == "string") {
        return a + b;
    }
    throw new Error("error: something");
}
```

It gets an error:

```
Type '(a: string | number, b: string | number) => string | number' is not assignable to type 'Sum'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

But when I use function declarations for overloading:

```
function sum2(a: number, b: number): number;
function sum2(a: string, b: string): string;
function sum2(a: number|string, b: number|string): number|string {
    if (typeof a == "number" && typeof b == "number") {
        return a + b;
    }
    if (typeof a == "string" && typeof b == "string") {
        return a + b;
    }
    throw new Error("error: something");
}
```

It works.
So, why does the first code get error ? 
Can everyone help me ?? :'(
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a type template. Something like:

```
type Sum<T> = (a: T, b: T) => T;
```

and use your function as:

```
let sum: Sum<string> = function(a: string, b: string): string {...}

let sum: Sum<number> = function(a: number, b: number): number {...}
```

This will throw a type error if you mix `string` and `number`. For example:

```
//throw type error
let sum: Sum<number> = function(a: number, b: string): number {...}
```

Comment: but I want it will get error when I put sum(1, "2") before the function's execution like the second code does, not when "throw new Error("error: something")" occurs. 
When I fix function return type from "number|string" to "any", it works but I want it to return number or string only

Comment: @Sake I understand. I updated my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The correct type for the method is

`(a: string | number, b: string | number): string | number`

so you can declare it like this:

```
type Sum = {
    (a: string | number, b: string | number): string | number
}
```

The type you've declared is expecting either a

- `(number, number): number` or
- `(string, string): string`,

**but not**

- `(number|string, number|string): number|string`.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in a few words: in the first case typescript ensures type safety, in the second it's your responsibility to ensure type safety.

---

The error is right. You can't assign `(a: number|string, b: number|string) => number|string` to `(a: number, b: number) => number`, because of function [covariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html) in return type. Consider if your implementation would get two numbers as parameter and return a string. You would break the type contract. This is the reason why typescript is trying to help prevent the error.

When [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), you have to guarantee in the implementation that you satisfy your type contract. If you would return a string when inputing two number, then your implementation would be wrong. The problem is that in this case typescript wouldn't protest. This is just how overloading is done in typescript.

Assigning the overloaded function works because in that case the types match perfectly, and the type contract is guaranteed by your implementation of the overloads.